# how to avoid gaps in layout when resizing a floated element

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs floated left and displayed as squares :

```
aa bb cc dd ee
aa bb cc dd ee
ff gg hh ii jj
ff gg hh ii jj
```

when I change the height of square b for instance, I get :

```
aa bb cc dd ee
aa bb cc dd ee
   bb ff gg hh
   bb ff gg hh
ii jj
ii jj
```

How can I get instead:

```
aa bb cc dd ee
aa bb cc dd ee
ff bb gg hh ii
ff bb gg hh ii
jj
jj
```

Thanks

Comment: you won't be able to achieve this with floating, you'll need relative/absolute positioning - but that brings lots of limitations, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be  it's better if you use JS [MANSONRY](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with floating. As sad as it seems, a table might be the best solution until the CSS3 Grid system gets more implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The way the document flow works, means you cannot do this with floats. An alternative in some cases is to use list-display: table and table-cell table-row but this has a lack of colspan support. Colspan is actually exactly what you want (colspan of 2 for the bb cell) and normal for the rest. A table is your best bet.